# How do i make it so that my bot autoamtticly kicks people when they have 3 warnings in discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

So here is my code for the warning system:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Du skal lige give mig en grund til din Advarsel!")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er blevet advaret med grunden: '{reason}'")
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })

  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er blevet advaret {len(current_user['reasons'])} gange : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}")
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er aldrig blevet advaret!")
```

all i'm asking is help with making so when they have 3 warnings in my reports.json file that they get kicked..

and i little disclaimer.. i didn't write all that code myself, i took it off stack and modified

Comment: I would start by trying to understand the code. If you don't do this, you will find it very difficult to modify/add new features like you are now.

Comment: @RossJacobs i understand it enough to make it myself in the future, it's just that i google  around and found nothing, i just don't know how to get started with trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for 3 warnings whenever you warn someone, and use `discord.Member` instead of `discord.User`.

```py
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.Member,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Du skal lige give mig en grund til din Advarsel!")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er blevet advaret med grunden: '{reason}'")
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })

  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)
  if len(report['users']) >= 3:
    await user.kick(reason='You reached 3 warnings')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.Member):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er blevet advaret {len(current_user['reasons'])} gange : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}")
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} er aldrig blevet advaret!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. unfortunately, it does not kick when it reaches 3 warning, but thanks anyway bud, i'll try and figure something out

Comment: Are you making sure the distinction between, say in my case, `521382555866628137`(an integer) and `'521382555866628137'`(a string)

Comment: I will try this when I wake up, I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me

Comment: everything as i see it should be in great order.. i can't seem to se any problem..